# Is Desmos Malfunctioning?

Tags: polynomials, roots, calculator

For the function: $f(x)=5x^3-10x$ we find the zeroes to be: $x=0, \sqrt{2}$, and $-\sqrt{2}$

However... If you let $a=\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$ in $5a^3-10a$

Desmos evaluates and says either of those equal $3.5527136788*10^{-15}$ (NOT $0$)!!!
Am I doing something incorrectly or is this Desmos' fault?

Image:[image: Desmos]

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1187415) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Desmos is not a true symbolic calculator, and the results you see are due to floating-point error incurred when the (inexact) values for $a$ are substituted into $5a^3-10a$ under (an also inexact) floating-point regime.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any sources that I could read about that elaborate more on this?

Comment: Nevermind, [Got it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)